# can we dispatch a KeyboardEvent of press & hold of a keyboard key?

Tags: javascript

how can i dispatch a KeyboardEvent in window of pressing a keyboard key ? in javascript ?
i have scenario in which user press and hold a specific keyboard button and then drag the mouse on screen it will draw a box , but i want to press that specific button programmatically on load of document , so whenever user will clickdown and drag mouse it will draw , is this possible ?

what is have a this keydown but its not working

```
 window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    'key': 'control'
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a tiny bit trickier to do the "mousedown" than, for example, onlick. Here's what I'm using:

```
$('div').on('mousedown mouseup', function mouseState(a) {
    if (a.type == "mousedown") {
        //whatever you like
    }
});
```

Tell me if it helped :D

Comment: its about keyboard button shouuld be pressed before mouse down